# Entering through legal / illegal solutions

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, sentence-structure, expressions, simile

Let's say that as a business man you have some problems with the tax ministry of your country. You are a very wealthy and influential individual that have friends in high places. Therefore it would not be surprising that there are many illegal solutions for you to do anything even removing your bad record in the ministry or escape from tax payment. 
You are talking to your friend, and he / she wants to advise you to follow up your affairs **"legally"** or **"illegally"**! 
I have made up a sentence here and I need to inquire if it is natural and idiomatic in this sense. If not, then please let me know what a native speaker would use instead:

> You'd better **enter through** the legal / illegal solution.

**Explanations:** I have tried to be witty using a simile for "legal" and "illegal" solutions and I have considered each one as a door/gate. If you want to perform your affairs based on each case, you must chose one path and subsequently enter through its respective gate. Therefore, I used **"enter through"**! 
I wonder if semantically I am allowed to use such a structure for this sense in the manner that I could imply my intention to the native listener clearly. If not, then please let me know what would a native speaker say in the same situation?

Comment: "enter through" is not an idiomatic expression and would not be natural to a native speaker in this context.  The word *navigate* is sometimes used in reference to law, especially when the details are overly complicated or difficult to understand.  Ex: "After my accident, I hired an attorney to help me navigate through tort law."

Comment: @Nmath That would make a good answer